# Chain rule with only partial differentiability assumed

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples

> Let $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ and $g:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^p$ be
> two functions that each possess a complete Jacobian matrix of partial
> derivatives $J_f$ and $J_g$ respectively, which are well-defined
> everywhere. Is it true that the composite $h=g\circ f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^p$
> also has a complete well-defined Jacobian matrix,
> and that $J_h(x)=J_g(f(x)) J_f(x)$ for each $x\in\mathbb R^m$?

I think that the answer is no. This looks like the chain rule, except that there is no assumption that $f$ and $g$ are differentiable. Having well-defined partial derivatives everywhere does not imply differentiability (classic counterexample is $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, $f(0,0)=0$). All proofs of the chain rule hinge on the assumption of differentiability.

However, I am struggling to come up with a counterexample to the claim.

Comment: Did you try using your $f$ as the function $g$ in the question?

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks for the tip. Taking $f(x)=(x,e^x-1)$ and $g$ as my classic counterexample, then $h=g\circ f$ isn't even continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Or even easier, $f(t) = (t,t)$. Yes.